# Retrieve radiobutton value through js

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript

[image]

**Visualforce**

```
<apex:page controller="OnlineFeed" id="testpage">
    <apex:form id="theform" >
        <apex:pageBlock title="OnlineFeedback" id="pb">
            <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1" title="RegistrationForm" collapsible="false" >
                <apex:pageBlockSectionItem id="pbsi1">
                    <apex:outputLabel >Name:</apex:outputLabel>
                    <apex:inputText value="{!TName}" />
                </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                <apex:pageBlockSectionItem id="pbsi2">
                    <apex:outputLabel >Email:</apex:outputLabel>
                    <apex:inputText value="{!TEmail}" />

                </apex:pageBlockSectionItem> 
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
            <apex:outputLabel >How satisfied were you with:</apex:outputLabel><br/>
            <h1>Key point #1</h1><br/>            
            <input class="radioBtn" type="radio" name="order" onchange="getSelectedValue()" value="Very Satisfied"/>Very Satisfied
            <input class="radioBtn" type="radio" name="order" onchange="getSelectedValue()" value="Satisfied" />Satisfied
            <input class="radioBtn" type="radio" name="order" onchange="getSelectedValue()" value="Neutral" />Neutral
            <input class="radioBtn" type="radio" name="order" onchange="getSelectedValue()" value="Unsatisfied" />Unsatisfied
            <input class="radioBtn" type="radio" name="order" onchange="getSelectedValue()" value="veryUnsatisfied" />veryUnsatisfied<br/>

            <apex:outputLabel >Feel free to add any other comments or suggestions:</apex:outputLabel><br/>
            <apex:inputTextarea cols="30" rows="10"/><br/>
            <apex:outputText >* The information given within the Feedback Form will be used for service improvement only and are strictly confidential.</apex:outputText>
            <apex:commandButton title="save" onclick="getSelectedValue();" action="{!submitted}" value="save" >
            </apex:commandButton>        
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
    <script>

    function getSelectedValue() {
        var radioBtns = document.getElementsByClassName("radioBtn");
        for(var i = 0; i < radioBtns.length; i++){
            if(radioBtns[i].checked)   
            {
                alert( 'button checked :'+radioBtns[i].value);
                document.getElementById("key1").value =radioBtns[i].value; 

                alert( 'button checked :'+radioBtns[i].value);
                document.getElementById("key2").value=radioBtns[i].value;
                alert( 'button checked :'+radioBtns[i].value);
                document.getElementById("key3").value=radioBtns[i].value;
                alert('button checked:'+radioBtns[i].value);
                document.getElementById("key4").value=radioBtns[i].value;
                alert('button checked:'+radioBtns[i].value);
                document.getElementById("key5").value=radioBtns[i].value;
                alert('button checked:'+radioBtns[i].value);
                var key1=radiBtns[i].value;
                return false ;
            }   
        }
    }
    </script>
</apex:page>
```

**Controller**

```
public class OnlineFeed 
{
    public string TName{set;get;}
    public string TEmail{set;get;}
    public string  key1 {set;get;}
    //public string getSelectedValue{set;get;}
    public string key2{set;get;}
    public string key3{set;get;}
    public string key4{set;get;}
    public string key5{set;get;}
    public OnlineFeed(){
        TName='';
        TEmail='';
        key1= ''; 
        key2='';
        key3='';
        key4='';
        key5='';
    }

    public void submitted(){
        RegistrationForm__c r=new RegistrationForm__c();
        r.Name = TName;
        r.Email__c=TEmail;
        r.Key_point_1__c=key1;
        r.Key_point_2__c=key2;
        r.Key_point_3__c=key3;
        r.Key_point_4__c=key4;
        r.Key_point_5__c=key5;
        insert r;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a specific question in there somewhere or just a code dump is all we get?

Answer (score 1):

You should change your logic as below.

1. Create radio option values in controller. Refer `getKeys()` method.
2. Display radio buttons using `<apex:selectRadio/>`. This way you dont need to use javascript to find out which is selected. It will be available by getter-setter like key1, key2, key3 etc.
3. Remove all javascript from visualforce page.

**Visualforce**

```
<apex:page controller="OnlineFeed" id="testpage">
    <apex:form id="theform" >
        <apex:pageBlock title="OnlineFeedback" id="pb">
            <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1" title="RegistrationForm" collapsible="false" >
                <apex:pageBlockSectionItem id="pbsi1">
                    <apex:outputLabel >Name:</apex:outputLabel>
                    <apex:inputText value="{!TName}" />
                </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                <apex:pageBlockSectionItem id="pbsi2">
                    <apex:outputLabel >Email:</apex:outputLabel>
                    <apex:inputText value="{!TEmail}" />

                </apex:pageBlockSectionItem> 
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
            <apex:outputLabel >How satisfied were you with:</apex:outputLabel><br/>
            <h1>Key point #1</h1><br/>            
            <apex:selectRadio value="{!key1}">
                <apex:selectOptions value="{!keys}"/>
            </apex:selectRadio><br/>
            <h1>Key point #2</h1><br/>            
            <apex:selectRadio value="{!key2}">
                <apex:selectOptions value="{!keys}"/>
            </apex:selectRadio><br/>
            <h1>Key point #3</h1><br/>            
            <apex:selectRadio value="{!key3}">
                <apex:selectOptions value="{!keys}"/>
            </apex:selectRadio><br/>
            <h1>Key point #4</h1><br/>            
            <apex:selectRadio value="{!key4}">
                <apex:selectOptions value="{!keys}"/>
            </apex:selectRadio><br/>
            <h1>Key point #5</h1><br/>            
            <apex:selectRadio value="{!key5}">
                <apex:selectOptions value="{!keys}"/>
            </apex:selectRadio><br/>
            <apex:outputLabel >Feel free to add any other comments or suggestions:</apex:outputLabel><br/>
            <apex:inputTextarea cols="30" rows="10"/><br/>
            <apex:outputText >* The information given within the Feedback Form will be used for service improvement only and are strictly confidential.</apex:outputText>
            <apex:commandButton title="save" action="{!submitted}" value="save" >
            </apex:commandButton>        
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>

</apex:page>
```

**Controller**

```
public class OnlineFeed 
{
    public string TName{set;get;}
    public string TEmail{set;get;}
    public string  key1 {set;get;}
    //public string getSelectedValue{set;get;}
    public string key2{set;get;}
    public string key3{set;get;}
    public string key4{set;get;}
    public string key5{set;get;}
    public OnlineFeed(){
        TName='';
        TEmail='';
        key1= ''; 
        key2='';
        key3='';
        key4='';
        key5='';
    }

    public List<SelectOption> getKeys() {
        List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>(); 
        options.add(new SelectOption('Very Satisfied','Very Satisfied')); 
        options.add(new SelectOption('Satisfied','Satisfied')); 
        options.add(new SelectOption('Neutral','Neutral'));
        options.add(new SelectOption('Unsatisfied','Unsatisfied'));
        options.add(new SelectOption('veryUnsatisfied','veryUnsatisfied'));
        return options; 
    }

    public void submitted(){
        RegistrationForm__c r=new RegistrationForm__c();
        r.Name = TName;
        r.Email__c=TEmail;
        r.Key_point_1__c=key1;
        r.Key_point_2__c=key2;
        r.Key_point_3__c=key3;
        r.Key_point_4__c=key4;
        r.Key_point_5__c=key5;
        insert r;
    }
}
```